# Error changing optional parameter values of methods

Tags: javascript, class, parameters

I have a class in JavaScript ...

```
class MyClass{

    static createElement(selector, settings = {
        name : 'element',
        enabled : true,
        color : '#EAEAEA'
    }){
          name = settings.name;
          enabled = settings.enabled;
          color = settings.color;

         // Do something...
    }

    static destroyElement(selector){
        // Do something...
    }

}
```

With two static methods, one to create elements and another to destroy them. Both methods receive the object selector as the first parameter and the method to create receives a second optional parameter for the object's configurations.

So it is assumed that the following configurations should be allowed:

```
MyClass.createElement(selector); // If you want to create an element with the default settings. (name: 'element', enabled: true and color: '#EAEAEA')

MyClass.createElement(selector, { name : 'element1' }); // A new element is created independent of the previous one but with the same configurations, it only changes the name.

MyClass.createElement(selector, { // Another independent element that changes the name and is deactivated, but that keeps the default color #EAEAEA
    name : 'element2',
    enabled : false
});
```

What is the problem? If I create an element leaving the `settings` parameters by default, everything works correctly, but if I create an object and change one of the`settings` parameters...

```
...createElement(selector, { name : 'element1' });
```

Then the other parameters (enabled and color) acquire a value of `undefined` when they should keep their default values (true and #EAEAEA) and should only change the value of `name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter is an object that you are replacing entirely, not merging it.

What about doing this:

```
static createElement(selector, settings = {}){

    settings = {

      // here is your default settings
      name : 'element',
      enabled : true,
      color : '#EAEAEA',

      // merging the parameter
      ...settings
    }


    name: settings.name,
    enabled: settings.enabled,
    color: settings.color,

}
```